# Crystal Reports Stock description

Tags: mysql, sql-server, crystal-reports, crystal-reports-2008, crystal-reports-8.5

I need to show a part of a description; if the description is Testing (6) (with brackets), I need to show only the 6 in the bracket. Any ideas,s, please?

tried the below command
mid ({tablename}, 1, inStr(tablename, "(")-1)

Comment: Why have you tagged SQL Server and MySQL here? How are 2 *completely different* RDBMS products directly related to the question?

Comment: Given the functions in your attempt are `mysql` functions it seems you have erroneously tagged `sqlserver`.

Answer (score 0):

Crystal Reports has an ***ExtractString()*** function, so use an expression like this:

```
ExtractString(yourstring, "(", ")");
```